# Widget Instance Block Bug

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, widgets

I've noticed that if you create a widget instance, then add a layout update, if you choose to add a widget instance to a single page, say cms_index_index, the next time you edit the widget instance, the block reference list only includes the blocks in default. If you wish to save a change you have to select a difference page, then change it back to re-populate the block drop down with the correct value for that page.

I've been routing around the blocks and templates for the last 20mins look for a solution. I seem to be getting some success by editing `Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Instance_Edit_Tab_Main_Layout::getDisplayOnContainers` and doing `$container['pages'] = $this->getPageGroups()` before returning the `$container` array. This seems to ensure that when `getDisplayOnContainers` is called in the template, the required handles are present on the page for the current instance. I've not had enough time to dive deep enough into this to see if there are any repercussions however.

Does anybody else have any experience with this issue?

P.s. Has anybody reviewed any of this functionality in Magento 2. I've not had enough free time to look, but I'm kind of hoping they'll go a step further and allow developers to add their own 'page types'.

Comment: Which block references do you have for the ```cms_index_index``` page that are not available in ```default```? Can you give an example?

Comment: You can add custom page types. Just put a `<label>` in your layout update handle in a *declared* layout file and ensure that handle is applied on your page.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug.

In the file

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/instance/edit/layout.phtml

**=> Replace around line 291**

`if (layoutHandleField = container.down('input.layout_handle_pattern')) {`

With

`if (layoutHandleField = $('layout_handle')) {`

Comment: I'd like to see this suggested in a custom template/theme for admin.

Comment: Was this ever fixed in 1.9.x/1.14.x? I'm still seeing this behavior out of box, unfortunately.

Comment: It's still bugged in 1.9.0.1 
Why is contributing to the code so hard lol

Comment: Been using @Paul Hachmang 's solution and it works great, but! I've found that with this change the block references for product pages no longer load. To fix I added an additional check afterward to see if layoutHandle is still blank, if so then try container.down('input.layout_handle_pattern') after all.